# BCP Error - SQLState 3700, Native Error = 102

Tags: sql-server, bcp, xp-cmdshell

Here is my BCPCommand, the rest of the query is tested and working fine, I have also tested the results in the BCP Query and is also in order

```
DECLARE @OutputFile VARCHAR(100) ,    
        @FilePath VARCHAR(100) ,    
        @bcpCommand VARCHAR(1000)

SET @bcpCommand = 'bcp "exec [dbo].[spRMAReturnBatchRecords] @strBatchNo = ' + @strBatchNo + 
                  ' , @dtBatchDate = ''' + CONVERT(VARchar(10),@dtBatchDate,120) +
                  ''' , @intBatchNo = ' + CONVERT(varchar(5),@intNextBatchNo) + '" queryout '

SET @FilePath = 'E:\RMA\Test\'
SET @OutputFile = 'RMA-' + @strBatchNo +'.txt'
--SET @bcpCommand = @bcpCommand + @FilePath + @OutputFile + ' -S'+ @@servername + ' -T -c'
SET @bcpCommand = @bcpCommand + @FilePath + @OutputFile + ' -c -T -S ' + @@SERVERNAME
exec master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand    
--TEST COMMAND      
--print @bcpCommand
--TEST OUTPUT                     
--exec spRMAReturnBatchRecords @strBatchNo, @dtBatchDate, @intNextBatchNo
```

The errors I am receiving currently are as follow:

```
Starting copy...
SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 2812
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Could not find stored procedure 'spRMAReturnBatchRecords'.
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Unable to resolve column level collations
BCP copy out failed
```

When I print my Cmd it reads as follows

```
bcp "exec [dbo].[spRMAReturnBatchRecords] @strBatchNo = SN001 , @dtBatchDate = '2014-04-02' , @intBatchNo = 1" queryout E:\RMA\Test\RMA-SN001.txt -c -T -S [omitted but correct]
```

I then paste everything between the "double quotes" into a new query with current connections and it executes without problems.

```
exec [spRMAReturnBatchRecords] @strBatchNo = SN006 , @dtBatchDate = '2014-04-02' , @intBatchNo = 6
```

Please assist.

Comment: Try `-d database_name`

Comment: I'm surprised you get away with quotes around the batch number; I would have expected `@strBatchNo = 'SN006'`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the name of the database to the query: `[MyDatabase].[dbo].[spRMAReturnBatchRecords]`.

Depending on the kind of output you expect, you might have to specify a separator if it's comma separated (use `-t ^` or whatever separator you like).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in your source SQL:

```
Use DatabaseName

Select column1 from Table1
```

Then you don't have to add the qualification in the statement itself.